# How to Verify Phone Number via Whatsapp for Business?

Tags: whatsapp, sms-verification

How to verify phone number validity via **Whatsapp for Business**?

**The flow should be like this:**

1. User input their phone number into mobile apps.
2. System sends 4 digits of code from **Whatsapp for Business.**
3. User input the digits into mobile apps.
4. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp has only announced the business version of their platform. 
WhatsApp Business is not yet available for iOS and there is no API to integrate WhatsApp in your own systems.

BookMyShow, an indian company was a member of whatsapp api tester project and said it would make WhatsApp a default ticket confirmation channel for all its users in the near future. [Source](https://yourstory.com/2017/09/bookmyshows-product-team-decrypts-how-whatsapp-for-business-works/)

So, there is no way to use whatsapp api and whatsapp team official did not announced anything about api.